# How to change gfortran version

Tags: macos, homebrew, gfortran

I am using [Bellhop ray tracing](http://oalib.hlsresearch.com/AcousticsToolbox/) algorithm for MacOS. I have downloaded the source code for MacOS without the binaries.

I want to change my gfortran version from 9.2.0 to 8.3.0. 
I installed it using homebrew. I have version 9.2.0 installed. I have it installed at /usr/bin/

I cannot seem to find any commands online to change the version.

```
gfortran -dumpversion
```

This gave me my version number but I cannot seem to find a command to get a different version.

I am working on macOS (Mojave V 10.14.6). I installed it using homebrew in /usr/local/bin/gfortran. I have version 9.2.0 installed.

```
type gfortran
```

Gives me the output:

```
 /usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

Update: I believe I have 8.3.0 now downloaded by erasing 9.2.0 and downloading gfortran-8. I needed to completely remove it from my system before downloading a different version.

Comment: You need to tell us what kid of operating system you have and how you installed your present gfortran. Do you have the other version installed? If yes where? How did you install it?

Comment: You should [edit] your question. Don't use comments for important information.

Comment: It seems unlikely that **homebrew** would install in `/usr/bin`. AFAIK, it always installs links in `/usr/local/bin`. If you run `gfortran` by typing `gfortran` you should paste the output of `type gfortran` into your question so we can see which one you are really using or if you have aliased it or made a `bash` wrapper around it.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but I would **guess**  `gfortran v8` is a part of `gcc@8`, so I would make a Time Machine backup, and remove your `gcc v9` with `brew rm gcc` and install `gcc v8` with `brew install gcc@8` and see what happens!

Comment: @MarkSetchell install gcc@8 did not work for me. gfortran -dumpversion  says that gfortran is unrecognized.

Comment: Did you check what `gcc@8` installed with `brew ls --verbose gcc@8 | grep -i gfortran` ?

Comment: Did you run `hash -r` after installing `gcc@8` to make your shell re-parse all the directories on your PATH?

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin18-gfortran-8
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/bin/gfortran-8
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.a
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.spec
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.5.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/share/man/man1/gfortran-8.1

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did run hash -r after installation

Comment: So maybe there is a new binary in `/usr/local/bin`? Did you try `ls /usr/local/bin/*gfor*`?

Comment: Yes there appear to be two new files in there /usr/local/bin/gfortran-8             and           /usr/local/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin18-gfortran-8

Comment: @MarkSetchell do i need to move these binaries? Sorry I am new to compilers!

Comment: No, I think these are the ones you should be using! Try `gfortran-8 -dumpversion`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have now encountered a new error. I have described it here. Please help if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051538/gfortran-error-libgfortran-spec-no-such-file-or-directory