# gfortran: error: libgfortran.spec: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, path, gfortran

I am attempting to install and run gfortran-8 on macOS with the following makefile. I installed it from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ (8.3 version). I keep getting this error:

```
gfortran: error: libgfortran.spec: No such file or directory
```

I know libhfortran.spec is located in /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.spec. I have added it to my etc/paths and my .bash_profile. I have also uninstalled gfortran and reinstalled it. Anyone have a clue on what I might be missing? I am attaching my makefile below.

Makefile: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y_Zo2dSYI32dQpwMtdUy5rWB8avDHXor

Comment: Why have you started a new question, when we haven't solved the last one... https://stackoverflow.com/q/61021444/2836621 ? What happened when you tried the suggestions there - please click `edit` under that question and update what you did and what happened. Thank you. Also, why are you mixing **homebrew** gortran with something you have partially-installed yourself via a `Makefile` - I can't help thinking you are making problems for yourself.

Comment: I need to buildout the bellhop ray tracing algorithm to use with Matlab. I need a gfortran compiler to build my binaries. However when I run my makefile from bellhop, I keep getting the error i have described above. Here is the bellhop link: http://oalib.hlsresearch.com/AcousticsToolbox/

Comment: Odd, I have built oalib, including bellhop, with multiple versions of gfortran.

Comment: do you know where your libgfortran.spec is located? @evets

Comment: It is located where it is suppose to be, i.e., `/usr/local/lib/gcc9/libgfortran.spec`.  Note, I don't use MacOS, so that's likely your problem.  The path you show above appears messed up.  The `Cellar/gcc@8/8.4.0` comes from where?

Comment: @evets Cellar is a folder created by homebrew

Answer (score 0):

**Bellhop Macintosh Installation**

- Note: I know gfortran is now part of gcc but newest `at` version still only works with older gfotran compilers. If you have Catalina as well, don’t worry this will still work on Mojave as well as on Catalina. I had tested it.
- Go to this [link](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases).
- [Download](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/8.2)
  [image]
- Install the downloaded `gfortran-8.2-Mojave.dmg`, this compiler is being used by the at to create binaries for your MacOS.
- Go to the path where you extracted `at` folder. (In Mac you don’t need windows binary, you need to compile using gfotran compiler.)
- Execute the following commands in the at folder.

[image]

- Once you installed. Close all the terminals.
- Open new terminal. Do as follows:
- In your terminal, type this:
  echo $PATH
- Above command give you current path in your zsh file, If you have one.
- Add bellhop to your zsh file. You can use these commands in terminal:

  ```sh
  cd
  nano .zsh
  ```

[image]

- Please note that there is no Bellhop in the path right now, so we are going to add that by adding the following line in the .zsh file, Copy and paste below list (change the path accordingly)
  `export PATH=your_local_macOS_path/at:your_local_macOS_path/at/Bellhop:$PATH$`
- For me, it was:
  `export PATH=/Users/jaypatel/Downloads/at:/Users/jaypatel/Downloads/at/Bellhop:$PATH$`
- Refer the screenshot below for more details.
  [image]
  [image]
- Once you’re done, press ctrl+X and it will ask you do you want to save your file, type Y and press enter and it will save the path successfully.
- And now source `~/.zsh` to your terminal using this command :

  ```sh
  source ~/.zsh
  echo $PATH
  ```
- This means your acoustic toolbox and bellhop.exe are in path’s now.
- And now source `~/.zsh` to your terminal using this command : `source ~/.zsh`
  [image]
- And **Voila**, Your `Bellhop` is successfully installed.

**Reference :**

- You can find more details [here](https://github.com/patel999jay/Bellhop-ARLPY-ECED6575).

Comment: @VladimirF : I have updated my answer. Thanks.